# 4.24 LAB: Homework Find largest absolute number Java

Tags: java

I am trying to print the largest number using absolute Math. methods. Except when ran, I get a different number.

Write a program whose inputs are three integers, and whose output is the largest (absolute) of the three values.

Ex: If the input is:

10 -30 29
the output is:

30

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = in.nextInt();
        int y = in.nextInt();
        int z = in.nextInt();
        if( x > y && x > z) {
            System.out.print(Math.abs(x)); 
        }  else if ( y > x && y > z) {
            System.out.print(Math.abs(y));
        }     else if ( z > x && z > y) ; {
            System.out.print(Math.abs(z));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you do some reading as to what `Math.abs` does.

Comment: Doesn’t it return the absolute value of a number?

Comment: You know that the semicolon here: `else if ( z > x && z > y) ; {...` short-circuits the else condition

Comment: Didn’t work. Prints 29

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int- Just take absolute of each of x,y,z and then take the max of those.. so -30 -> +30 etc! Useful to know Integer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html has MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE.. Use 4th var and set to MIN_VALUE - then check each one replacing 4th values if an of X,Y or Z is greater than the  4th var. Print that at the end.

Comment: https://code.sololearn.com/c605Z0M5c8GX/#java - lol identical to answer

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the conditionals if you introduce another variable (if that's allowed). Also you'll want to get the absolute value of each input when setting them so that all the comparisons are done with positive integers. Here's what I used and it worked great

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = Math.abs(in.nextInt());
        int y = Math.abs(in.nextInt());
        int z = Math.abs(in.nextInt());

        int largest = x;
        if (y > largest) {
            largest = y;
        }
        if (z > largest) {
            largest = z;
        }
        System.out.print(largest);
    }
}
```

And if you're interested in using the ternary operator in order to slim things down a bit

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = Math.abs(in.nextInt());
        int y = Math.abs(in.nextInt());
        int z = Math.abs(in.nextInt());

        int largest = x > y ? x : y;
        largest = z > largest ? z : largest;
        System.out.print(largest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely designed, my problem I believe was not putting Math.abs correctly for the declarations. Instead, after and underneath the if and else if statements would not print the biggest number. This seems to work fine. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [`Math.abs(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-) then I would assume you can use [`Math.max(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max-int-int-) and thus the problem can be solved like

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = in.nextInt(), y = in.nextInt(), z = in.nextInt();
System.out.println(Math.max(Math.max(Math.abs(z), Math.abs(y)), Math.abs(x)));
```

As for your current code, you are comparing the original values (not the absolute values) and you should probably end with an `else` (so you have a default result) -

```
if (Math.abs(x) > Math.abs(y) && Math.abs(x) > Math.abs(z)) {
    System.out.print(Math.abs(x));
} else if (Math.abs(y) > Math.abs(x) && Math.abs(y) > Math.abs(z)) {
    System.out.print(Math.abs(y));
} else { // you want a default case, and if you get here 'z' is it.
    System.out.print(Math.abs(z));
}
```

Comment: I see. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to a similar problem using a ternary operator. One method is used to find the largest number, another method is used to find the smallest number out of three.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   
   public static int largestNumber(int num1, int num2, int num3){
      int largestNumber = num1>num2?(num1>num3?num1:num3):(num2>num3?num2:num3);
      return largestNumber;
   }
          
   public static int smallestNumber(int num1, int num2, int num3){
      int smallestNumber = num3<(num1<num2?num1:num2)?num3:(num1<num2?num1:num2);
      return smallestNumber;
   }
          
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int a = scnr.nextInt();
      int b = scnr.nextInt();
      int c = scnr.nextInt();
      
      System.out.println("largest: " + largestNumber(a,b,c));
      System.out.println("smallest: " + smallestNumber(a,b,c));   
   }
}
```